# Coloring a scatter plot from pandas itertuples?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, iteration

I have a dataframe that has coordinates in one column, and an orientation in the other:

[image]

I'm trying to scatter plot the coordinates and then colour them by their orientation:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
   x, y = row.coords[:,1], row.coords[:,0]
   plt.scatter(x,y, c=df.orientation)
```

This plots the coordinates fine but not the orientation as it's still within the itertuple loop. Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: can you please include the example code to generate your data frame? Or include an example data frame? I am not sure what your trying to do. Perhaps you can include an image of the plot you have right now, rather than an image of your dataframe contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each row has only one color, you need to explicitly set that color for the row. In order to get a color from a certain numeric orientation value, you need to create a colormap and a norm. The [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) can be any of your choice. The norm needs to be set using the complete range of the 'orientation' column.
Using the norm (to get a value between 0 and 1) you can index the colormap and obtain an rgb-value.

As `plt.scatter` tries to verify whether you are giving one single color for all points together or one color per point, rgb values can cause confusion. Therefore, it is safest to create an array around the color value (so `c=[cmap(norm(row.orientation))]` instead of just `c=cmap(norm(row.orientation))`).

The colormap and norm can also be used to create an accompanying colorbar.

Here is some example code to get you started:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 30
df = pd.DataFrame({'coords': [np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(np.random.randint(5, 50), 2)) + np.random.uniform(0, 50, 2)
                              for _ in range(N)],
                   'orientation': np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)})
cmap = plt.get_cmap('magma')
norm = plt.Normalize(df.orientation.min(), df.orientation.max())
for row in df.itertuples():
    coords = np.array(row.coords)
    x, y = coords[:, 1], coords[:, 0]
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=[cmap(norm(row.orientation))])
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm), label='orientation')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: I added .set_array([]) to the ScalarMappable which seemed to fix this message 'You must first set_array for mappable'. Thanks, really appreciate your help!

Comment: (You may be running an older version of matplotlib where `ScalarMappable` still needed `set_array([])`. It should be solved since version 3.1.0.)

Answer (score 0):

You iterate by row, so you should use the same syntax as you did for x and y : `c=row.orientation`